# how create a datagrid with panel dynamically?

Tags: c#, winforms

I'm french, so sorry for my bad english... But I hope that you will help me ;)

I'm developing a soft in c# with lot of information store in DB, like information about people.

I want display these information with a beautiful UI, like that :

[image]

For that, I created :

- a first panel in Visual
- a class for create sub panel dynamically

I make a loop and for each person, I call a method "createPanel" with the information of each person, and these sub panels created are added to the parent panel. The ID of each person is store in the "tag" parameter of the sub panel.

All work fine, but I don't really know how to add event in each sub panel.
As you can see in the link above, the user can click on a bookmark, or a icon for show a menu (the round with 3 point = icon "menu").

My question is how to add event for each sub panel dynamically ? For example I want display a menu for each sub panel when I click on the icon "menu", get the id store in the "tag" of the sub panel, and show a new form for manage information.

Thx for your help, I can add my code if necessary :)

Comment: What API is this? ASP.NET? MVC? WinForms? WPF?

Comment: it's winforms :)

Comment: Please provide code of what you have tried.

Comment: OK I will add the code tomorrow, I'm not at home now !

Comment: Try a listview.  See following codeproject : https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/16009/A-Much-Easier-to-Use-ListView-2

Comment: I already make a version like your link, but now I want to dev a version more beautiful ;) I upload a picture of the result tomorrow with my code !

Comment: Preview when the soft is run : https://ibb.co/gZ8F1dk

And my class : https://textuploader.com/1apuy

I call "creerPanelEnfant" for each sub panel, I tested to add a menu by creating a "ToolStripMenu" (CMSEnfants in my code) dynamically, but it's really ... Efficient like that I think ^^

Comment: My opinion on this is if you want to create "UI friendly" application do not use winforms. I am developing my programs in winform since it is easier to understand and manipulate (for me) but when comes to UI it doesn't have much options or they are slow. What i would recommend you is learn WPF and do it there.

Comment: Yes I know but I don't know WPF (and XAML...) :/ And I have not the time for learn a new language ... Snirf !

Comment: @benben26 that's what this question asks though. Winforms controls are created dynamically too. Anything you do in a designer actually generates code in `InitializeComponents()`. Your question actually asks for a *tutorial* on from layout, docking, data binding, grids, the works. Might as well start with a *modern* environment that doesn't need workarounds to display what you posted

Comment: @benben26 WPF and XAML aren't languages. They are UI stacks, the same as Winforms. The image you posted can be built relatively easily with WPF. It would require a *LOT* of hacks using Winforms. You can dock the top bar at the form's top but how are you going to create the 3 columns?

Answer (score -1):

Make a own user control for the panels you want to display containing all the controls from the toolbox you need.

```
public partial class MyControl : UserControl
{
  ...
}
```

In "MyControl" you define events for all things that can happen and must be handled **externally** of the control. Same as e.g. "SelectedIndexChanged" for combobox.

Your control class would then look like this:

```
public partial class MyControl : UserControl
{
   public event EventHandler<MyImportantEventA> OnImportantThingHappend;

   //Event-Invoker
   protected virtual void OnOnImportantThingHappend(MyImportantEventA e)
        {
            OnImportantThingHappend?.Invoke(this, e);
        }
}

//Data of your event. Customize as you like/need.
public class MyImportantEventA : EventArgs   
 {
            public string Message { get; set; }
 }
```

When you add your control dynamically, bind to the event(s) of your control:

```
myUserControl.OnImportantThingHappend += DoSomethingWithEvent;
```

Things the control can handle it self, don't need to be exposed as events.
E.g.:

"Close" may be something that must be handled externally. You need to remove the control, rearange you controls etc.

"Show Details" probably is something that can be handled completely inside of your control. Your control shows a message box or a fancy tooltip.

Comment: This doesn't answer the question. It's not even a starting point on how to create a user control. *Why* use a user control in the first place? This won't make docking, stacking easier.

Comment: The question was not about stacking. It was about how to get all the events needed. "My question is how to add event for each sub panel dynamically ? For example I want display a menu for each sub panel when I click on the icon "menu""

Comment: The question isn't about events. It's about creating a UI with panels, menus, commands. You don't do that with a UserControl and events. You *don't* handle commands right in the controls that invoke them. Otherwise you'd have to duplicate code in the menu items, buttons, forms that implement the same command. You create separate classes and route UI events to them in a way that doesn't add a hard dependency between UI and command. Winforms requires extra work to do that while WPF has the command routing concept already

Comment: Hello, I have not tested your code at this time, but this morning I have successfully use the event on each sub panel. I just store the ID in the "tag" parameter of the picturebox (menu or favorite for example), and when I click on the picturebox, I get the ID, and show a new form with the information corresponding to the ID :) 

This work fine :)

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos Don't know what you are talking about. The question was  exactly about events (s. quote above comment) and to have events in a control and handle them is perfect doing in Winforms. Or does your Winforms combobox expose commands? What your are suggesting is overkill for such a simple problem.

Comment: @benben26 I'm doing Winforms for ~15 years as a professional. I guess I haven't used the "Tag" property since 16 years :-) There is no need to use tags, believe me. Make a own control for your ticket-panels, provide them the data they need to display (s. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54137475/binding-data-to-controls-in-a-repeating-user-control-with-c-winforms/54177183#54177183) and handle as much as possible in your control. For stuff which needs to be handled externally, provide events. It's not a good idea to identify ~50 buttons by their tags.